# Regex with matcher returning only the first result

Tags: java, regex

Hello I got a problem using the regex with Java.

I'm trying to parse this :

```
*whatever string*
<AttributeDesignator AttributeId="MyIDToParse"
DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
Category="theCategoryIWantToParse"
MustBePresent="false"
/>
*whatever string ***that may contain the same regular expression again*** *
```

using this code (Pattern + Matcher)

```
        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("AttributeDesignator AttributeId=\"(.+?)\".*Category=\"(.+?)\"", Pattern.DOTALL);

    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(xml);
    while (matcher.find()) {
    String ID = matcher.group(1);
    String Category = matcher.group(2);
```

My problem is that my regexp returns only the first occurence of the pattern, even if I have a while(matcher.find())..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("AttributeDesignator +AttributeId=\"(.+?)\" +.*?Category=\"(.+?)", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Use non greedy instead of greedy quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is *Category=\"(.+) catcches all the remaining text. 
You must close it as Category=\"(.+)\".